# asciidoctor-pdf cannot load such file -- matrix (LoadError)

Tags: asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

I'm building an existing asciidoc project on a new machine and while it works on my old machine, on the new one it throws this error:

```
$ bundle exec asciidoctor-pdf book.adoc

bundler: failed to load command: asciidoctor-pdf (/book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/bin/asciidoctor-pdf)
/book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/prawn-2.4.0/lib/prawn/transformation_stack.rb:10:in `require': cannot load such file -- matrix (LoadError)
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/prawn-2.4.0/lib/prawn/transformation_stack.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/prawn-2.4.0/lib/prawn.rb:67:in `require_relative'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/prawn-2.4.0/lib/prawn.rb:67:in `<top (required)>'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/asciidoctor-pdf-1.6.2/lib/asciidoctor/pdf.rb:5:in `require'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/asciidoctor-pdf-1.6.2/lib/asciidoctor/pdf.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/asciidoctor-pdf-1.6.2/bin/asciidoctor-pdf:5:in `require'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/asciidoctor-pdf-1.6.2/bin/asciidoctor-pdf:5:in `<top (required)>'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/bin/asciidoctor-pdf:25:in `load'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/bin/asciidoctor-pdf:25:in `<top (required)>'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler/cli.rb:484:in `exec'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.8/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:103:in `with_friendly_errors'
  from /book/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.8/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
  from /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
  from /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
```

I'm using `bundler` 2.3.8 and my `Gemfile` source is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'asciidoctor', "2.0.17"
gem 'asciidoctor-pdf', "1.6.2"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Cause

This `asciidoctor-pdf` error is casued by a [`prawn` 2.4 compatibily issue with ruby 3.1](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/issues/1195) that will be solved in the next prawn release.

Since `prawn` 2.4 is a dependency of `asciidoctor-pdf` 1.6.2, it doesn't works on `ruby` > 3.0.x.

### Solution

In order to avoid this error, you need to use a compatible `ruby` version like 3.0.3 or >2.5.

You can install it easily using a version manager like [rvm](https://rvm.io/) or [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/).

Comment: adding `gem "matrix", "~> 0.4"` helped, as suggested in the linked issue. this should be ragarded as temporary fix though.